# Can't get response from Server

Tags: c#, java, android, sockets, tcplistener

Hello everyone and thank you for taking your time on helping me resolve my issue. I'm at the very beginning with programming so please forgive me if I'm asking stupid questions.

I have a Server in my Windows Form application written in C#, and a client that connects to the Server. The client is an app for Android written in Java.

I can successfully connect and send data (which is an XML String) to the Server. My problem is, no matter what I do, I can't get response from Server in the form of "Bla bla bla the string was successfully received thank you". Either it's happening because Server did not send data, or my Client did not receive it. I can't figure it out, although I've searched and tried different combination of code.

So below is the code for Server and Client:

Client:

```
public void functionSend (View view)
{
    RadioGroup type = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupType);
    TextView ip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id._ip);
    TextView port = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.port);
    TextView event = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.event);
    TextView amount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amount);
    TextView comment = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.comment);
    Spinner currency = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id._currencySpinner);
    _ip = ip.getText().toString();
    _event = event.getText().toString();
    _amount = amount.getText().toString();
    _comment = comment.getText().toString();
    if (_comment.equals(""))
    {
        _comment = "empty";
    }
    _currency = currency.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if (port.getText().toString().equals(""))
    {
        _port = 3344; port.setText("3344");
    }
    else
    {
        _port = Integer.parseInt(port.getText().toString());
    }
    rbID = type.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    if (rbID == R.id.RadioButtonOutgo)
    {
        _type = "outgo";
    }
    else
    {
        _type = "income";
    }

    //------formam XML string--------
    method = "create event";
    key = "123456";
    //formam stringul xml care i-l vom transmite catre server
    clientXMLStream = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>";
    clientXMLStream = clientXMLStream + "\n <Client>";
    clientXMLStream = clientXMLStream +  "\n <ClientKey>" + key + "</ClientKey>";
    clientXMLStream = clientXMLStream +  "\n <Method>" + method + "</Method>";
    clientXMLStream = clientXMLStream +  "\n <ForDay>" + day + "</ForDay>";
    clientXMLStream = clientXMLStream +  "\n <ForMonth>" + (month+1) + "</ForMonth>";
    clientXMLStream = clientXMLStream +  "\n <ForYear>" + year + "</ForYear>";
    clientXMLStream = clientXMLStream +  "\n <Event>" + _event + "</Event>";
    clientXMLStream = clientXMLStream +  "\n <Amount>" + _amount + "</Amount>";
    clientXMLStream = clientXMLStream +  "\n <Type>";
    clientXMLStream = clientXMLStream +  _type + "</Type>";
    clientXMLStream = clientXMLStream +  "\n <Currency>" + _currency + "</Currency>";
    clientXMLStream = clientXMLStream +  "\n <Comment>";
    clientXMLStream = clientXMLStream +  _comment + "</Comment>";
    clientXMLStream = clientXMLStream +  "\n </Client>";
    //--------------------------------
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
    DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
    try
    {
        Socket socket = null;
        socket = new Socket(_ip, _port);
        //socket.setSoTimeout(2000);
        dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(clientXMLStream.toString());
        event.setText(dataInputStream.readUTF().toString());
        dataOutputStream.flush();
        socket.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

Here is Server code:

```
    void startServer()
{
    Thread listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(listenToMessages));
    listenThread.Start();
}

public void listenToMessages()
{
    tcplistener.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        TcpClient client = tcplistener.AcceptTcpClient();
        Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
        clientThread.Start(client);
    }
}

public void HandleClientComm(object client)
{
    TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
    NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

    byte[] message = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead;

    while (true)
    {
        bytesRead = 0;

        try
        {
            bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
            NetworkStream _clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

            ASCIIEncoding _encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] buffer = _encoder.GetBytes("Some Contacts as a string!");
            byte[] lengthBuffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(buffer.Length);
            clientStream.Write(lengthBuffer, 0, lengthBuffer.Length);
            clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            clientStream.Flush();
            tcpClient.Close();

            //clientStream.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            break;
        }

        if (bytesRead == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        tcpClient.Close();
        ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
        processRemoteInputs(encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));
        //reply

    }
}

void stopServer()
{

}

void processRemoteInputs(String clientXmlString)
{
    XmlDocument remote = new XmlDocument();
    remote.LoadXml(clientXmlString);
    XmlNode method = remote.SelectSingleNode(".//Client/Method");
    if (method.InnerText == "create event")
    {
        XmlNode remoteDay = remote.SelectSingleNode(".//Client/ForDay");
        _neSelDay = Convert.ToInt16(remoteDay.InnerText);
        XmlNode remoteMonth = remote.SelectSingleNode(".//Client/ForMonth");
        _neSelMonth = Convert.ToInt16(remoteMonth.InnerText);
        XmlNode remoteYear = remote.SelectSingleNode(".//Client/ForYear");
        _neSelYear = Convert.ToInt16(remoteYear.InnerText);
        XmlNode remoteEvent = remote.SelectSingleNode(".//Client/Event");
        String _remoteEvent = remoteEvent.InnerText;
        XmlNode remoteAmount = remote.SelectSingleNode(".//Client/Amount");
        String _remoteAmount = remoteAmount.InnerText;
        XmlNode remoteType = remote.SelectSingleNode(".//Client/Type");
        String _remoteType = remoteType.InnerText;
        XmlNode remoteCurrency = remote.SelectSingleNode(".//Client/Currency");
        String _remoteCurrency = remoteCurrency.InnerText;
        XmlNode remoteComment = remote.SelectSingleNode(".//Client/Comment");
        String _remoteComment = remoteComment.InnerText;
        addNewEvent(_remoteEvent, _remoteAmount, _remoteType, _remoteCurrency, _remoteComment);
        setMonthLabel(); clearAllCurrentRows();
        loadXmlIntoDataGridView(); displayMonthDebit(); _monthDataGrid.Rows[Convert.ToInt16(_neSelDay) - 1].Selected = true;
        _monthDataGrid.CurrentCell = _monthDataGrid.Rows[Convert.ToInt16(_neSelDay) - 1].Cells[0]; displayDetailedInfoOnRowSelect();
        displayMonthChart();
    }
}
```

Comment: for one, do something when you catch an exception. (extra tip : logging is good, printStacktrace is better)